# Why can this question be treated as a question with geometric random variable without any modifications?

Tags: probability, random-variables

> In an infinite sequence of flipping a fair coin - $0.5$ probability to get heads/tails. (every flip is independent from the others). 
> What is the expected value of number of flips until we get Heads then Tails?

My Attempt: 
I tried to think about the event HT as my R.V success. So let $X$ be the number of flips until we get HT. 
The probability to get HT in a row is $\frac{1}{4}$, as we need the coin to land on H and then immediately on T. 
But I thought to myself that a geometric RV doesn't really count those two as two flips, so I thought that for example: 
TTTHHHT -> My random variable $X$ would be $6$. 
So I set $Y=X+1$ and my answer was $E(X+1)=4+1=5$. 

But turns out the real answer is $4$. Why my method is wrong? where does my logic/understanding fall? 
Is it that $X$ is just the answer for this problem? but I can't see how that's right, or maybe I have issues in my geometric random variable understanding. 
Would appreciate any help, Thanks in advance!

Comment: I did not understand how you counted $5$

Comment: "real answer" from where?

Comment: @herbsteinberg The writer of the question, the final answer provided with it..

Comment: @MathLover I thought that making the success for $X$ being HT, as two flips, shifts the random variable back by one, lets say I got $TTHT$, then I got 1 fail 1 fail, 1 success, so my random variable (in my eyes) would give me $3$, and that's why I added another $1$, and got to $5$, as $E(X)=4$.

Comment: OK I see now but the random variable will count $HT$ as $2$.

Comment: @MathLover Could you explain why me merging two flips probabilities to define success for my random variable doesn't really change it's behaviour? Why does it count it as $2$ and not $1$?

Comment: But I do not understand your method. How are you calculating it without applying the law of total expectation? For example, if we had to get $HH$ in a row, what would $E(X)$ be by your method?

Comment: $E(X)$ is $4$ always, I defined it as a geometric random variable that counts the number of flips until we see an $HT$, and I calculated that the probability to see $HT$ is $\frac{1}{2}*\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{4}$, so $X\sim Geo(\frac{1}{4})$.

Comment: But $E(X)$ for two heads in a row is $6$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\xi_i$ be the result of the i-th coin toss, and let $X = \min_{n} \{n >0: \xi_n = T, \xi_{n-1}-H\}$
You can use the law of total probability, then you have
$$\mathbb E(X) = \mathbb E(X|\xi_1=H) \mathbb P(\xi_1=H) + \mathbb E(X|\xi_1=T) \mathbb P(\xi_1=T) $$
We can calculate the conditional expectations.
$$X|\xi_1=H \sim 1+Geo(1/2) \implies \mathbb E(X|\xi_1=H) = 1+2=3$$
$$E(X|\xi_1=T) = 1 + E(X)$$
If we substitute the results in the above equation, we get:
$$\mathbb E(X) = 3 \frac 12 + \mathbb (E(X)+1) \frac 12 $$
$$\mathbb E(X) = 4$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it. Say $X$ is the event of getting $H, T$ in a row. Based on the first flip, we have two cases -

$i$) The first flip is $H$ - Then we are seeking the next flip to be a $T$. If we get $T$, we are done but if we get $H$, we are again looking for a $T$ and so on.

$ii$) The first flip is $T$ - We spent a flip and we are again back to where we started, that is seeking $H, T$.

So, $E(X) = 1 + \frac{1}{2} E(X) + \frac{1}{2} E(T)$

Now we know $E(T) = 2$

So, $E(X) = 4$